# Remove Specific Plot Key Entries in JFreeChart

Tags: java, rendering, plot, jfreechart

I have an *XYPlot* in JFreeChart with multiple *XYDataset*s.  JFreeChart creates a key at the bottom of the plot with an entry for each series by default.  I would like to disable the drawing of entries for all of the series in *one* of my datasets.  **I do not want to disable the drawing of entries altogether.**  Is this possible without modifying the renderer?  Thanks!

Comment: By "without modifying the renderer" do you mean extending it or not calling setXXX methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this directly by calling setSeriesVisible() or setBaseSeriesVisible() on your render.

For the legend at the bottom you can use setSeriesVisibleInLegend() or setBaseSeriesVisibleInLegend()